# Appropriate heatgun for removing cellphone screens/backs

Tags: repair, heat

From watching a number of Youtube videos it appears that many cellphones require a heatgun (or equivalent) to remove the screens or backs.   Similary, Looking at a Huawei 10 lite phone backing, it appears I need to heat it up to get it to adhere properly.

How hot/big a heat gun should I be looking at as a general tool to help me hack my cellphones without substantial risk of damaging components due to excess heat?

Comment: If you look at the iFixit site, they have a pad, similar to a hot/cold pack for sports medicine wrapped in a towel (which would also do).  You warm it in a microwave (carefully) and set it on the device for 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to get what's called a hot air rework tool. It's basically a small, usually digital hot air gun. You can adjust the air flow and temperature accurately. Since you are working on a very expensive device it's worth the 50-60 bucks on Amazon.

https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwim2JbIt8TgAhWXVg0KHdhXAZgYABAfGgJxYg&sig=AOD64_36vNmm026oQN5wswhU3_F0NFlXiw&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwiFuJDIt8TgAhVCneAKHb6yC9QQwg96BAgKEB0&adurl=

Comment: check the accuracy of the temperature setting, using an oven thermometer or a meat thermometer, before you use it on a cell phone